# Beveling smooth corners

Tags: topology, bevel

I'm creating interior geometry in Blender. I'm going for a smoothed look, so I created the basic floorplan for my interior, beveled the corners which I wanted smooth, and then extruded the faces upwards.

What I'm having trouble with is beveling the ceiling so that it's also rounded out. It suffers at the corners because of the overlap, and I have no clue what to do with the topology, or in general, to make it appear how I want it to.

Included pictures of the geometry before beveling, and after beveling; at the ideal point I want it to be.

[image: Geometry with no ceiling bevel]

[image: Geometry beveled to ideal point, overlapping]

Answer (score 3):

Planning ahead may solve *some* cases like this. If you bevel the narrower bevel connecting to a wider one first, you will have this problem, but if you bevel the wide one first, then it's OK:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's no other trick than to fix it manually, select all these vertices and merge (then move it so that the edges are parallel):

[image]

Same for these ones:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Or you could change to this topology afterwards with some <kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]